# Unable to display my template html in inappbrowser/new window

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I wanted to display my templates using angularjs inappbrowser, but at last I was getting an error

```
code":-1100,"message":"The requested URL was not found on this server.",
```

My codes:

> $cordovaInAppBrowser.open('templates/payment.html', '_blank').then(function(event){
>       console.log('Open successfully');
>   }, function(event) {
>   });

When I try to replace the url to external, it is working. So, are the inappbrowser must be external link?

Any solution for open my template in new window?

Comment: Try absolute path of your template.

Comment: how did I know absolute path for my template?I am test on my ios simulator.

Comment: Try cordova-plugin-file to resolve fullpath of the file. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

Comment: I am follow the example from http://stackoverflow.com/a/34357114/6234968 but unable to open "payment.html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i success to display my template in new window/inappbrower. 
My file structure is "templates/Home/payment.html"

So, the code will be

> var ref= $cordovaInAppBrowser.open('templates/Home/payment.html', '_blank', options)
>           .then(function(event) {
>               console.log('Open Url success', event);
>           },function(event) {
>               // error
>               });

Hopes this can help.